# splitting the java string

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String split not returning empty results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764687/string-split-not-returning-empty-results)

I am having a string of words separated by comma(,) and I need to tokenize or split the main string into substrings. For e.g, `string="file1,param1,file2,param2,file3,"` 
What the string means is, a list of all file names and the parameter passed to it. Like,
for file1--> param1,
file2-->param2 and
file3 nothing parameter exists.

So I need to extract the file names and params, if any. If no params I need to get the empty string("").

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class XStringTokenizer {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = new String("File1,param1,File2,");
        List list = new ArrayList();
        System.out.println(str.split(",").length);
        String[] string = str.split(",");
        for(int i=0;i<string.length;i++){
            list.add(string[i]);
        }
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Current output for the above sample code is [File1,param1,File2] but expected output is [File1,param1,File2,]. Basically I should not miss the end empty string after the 3rd comma in the above `str` String.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you should use

```
 String[] string = str.split(",",-1);
```

The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) for String.split(String,int) states " If n is non-positive then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible and the array can have any length."

Comment: yes, i corrected my code by passing n = -1 to split method to get the desired result. Thanks

Comment: if this was the correct one please set the answer as your accepted answer please. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use [public String[] split(String regex,
                      int limit)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) with negative limit

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last `,` or consider using [Apache Commons Lang package](http://commons.apache.org/lang), that includes `StringUtils.join()`, which does exatcly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = new String("File1,param1,File2,");
java.util.Tokenizer tk= new java.util.Tokenizer(str,",");
while(tk.hasMoreTokens()) {
    String tokenFile= tk.nextToken();
    String tokenParam= tk.nextToken();
    // do things...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the str.split(",") is only splitting when the comma is followed by some character rather than "the nothing", because the comma is the last character of your string. So the split won´t recognize it as a separator in that case and won't generate the 4th string you're expecting in your array because it would be null.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it by checking if the string ends with a ',' then add a null string in the list..And u need to do this at the end

```
if(str.endsWith(',')) list.add("");
```

Answer (score -2):

That's not how String.split works.

> Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29

You could check if the string ends in a comma and then add the empty string yourself