# split() nothing between delimiters = empty string

Tags: java

Imagine you have:

```
String string = "A;B;;D";
String[] split = string.split(";");
```

I want the result to be:

```
split[0] = "A";
split[1] = "B";
split[2] = "";
split[3] = "D";
```

But the result is:

```
split[0] = "A";
split[1] = "B";
split[2] = "D";
```

Is there a simple PROPER way to to this?

Comment: Java does what you are asking for, are you sure you did not eliminate the problem in simplifying the example?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764687/string-split-not-returning-empty-results?rq=1

Comment: I got the result as expected. Can you post your full code? Maybe the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: All those answers while the `split` method simply works as expected in the example given. Do you people need those mod points that badly?

Comment: I can't understand why this was closed or why it was considered "too localized". It was exactly what I was looking for, as was the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the overloaded method [`split(String regex, int limit)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
String string = "A;B;;D";
String[] split = string.split(";", -1);
```

---

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

```
The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with these parameters:

    Regex   Limit   Result
    :   2   { "boo", "and:foo" }
    :   5   { "boo", "and", "foo" }
    :   -2  { "boo", "and", "foo" }
    o   5   { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }
    o   -2  { "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }
    o   0   { "b", "", ":and:f" }
```

Comment: 0 works as the second parameter as well: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String, int)

Answer (score 4):

Personally I'd use [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) class:

```
Iterable<String> bits = Splitter.on(';').split(string);
```

If you *wanted* it to omit empty strings, you'd just use:

```
Iterable<String> bits = Splitter.on(';').omitEmptyStrings().split(string);
```

No nasty implicit regexes, and everything does what it says on the tin. Much nicer :)

In real life I'd probably create the splitter *once* as a static final variable. (If you're thinking that importing Guava for the sake of a single class is overkill, have a look at the rest of the library. It's incredibly useful - I wouldn't want to develop in Java without it.)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to include a second parameter in the split function, this being the smallest amount of characters you'll accept between splits, in your case 0.

So the call should look like:

```
String[] split = string.split(";", 0);
```

Use a limit of 0 to discard trailing empty strings, or a negative value to keep them.
Find the docs here: [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Comment: I don't think limit represents _"the smallest amount fo characters you'll accept between splits"_, it's more the maximal amount of matches that can occur, thus the maximum size of the resulting array. From the JavaDoc, the resulting array `{ "b", "", ":and:f", "", "" }` has a limit of 5, yet index 1 is an empty string.